# What is Pact provider is it an application or an Api Endpoint?

Tags: pact

We have a situation where we have an application that hosts 10-20 API’s for which we plan to implement contact testing . Will it be better to have a pact per Api against a consumer application or one pact for application which as acts as provider and  each Api acts as separate interaction?

Answer (score 0):

A pact (contract) is usually between two *applications*. If the *provider* application provides multiple endpoints or resources (what I think you're referring to as "APIs") then they are modelled as one or more interactions (test cases).

> ...or one pact for application which as acts as provider and each Api acts as separate interaction?

This is what you want, I think.

Answer (score 0):

There are some popular CDC(Consumer Driven Contracts) testing solution, Spring provides Spring Cloud Contracts which is integrated tightly with Spring, Pact is another great solution for CDC .

In [my micro-service examples](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-microservice-sample), I provides examples using  Pact and Spring Cloud Contracts.

The API consumer(which consumes APIs) and provider(which provides APIs) sides maintains a contract to ensure the API consistence.

Ideally the contract for each APIs should per consumer(if you are following B4F pattern, if not we can ignore the difference from consumers) and per version.  Eg. user client v1.0, and v2.0 could be different.